# Why does the area of a circle come into play?

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image]

I am confused about this problem.

First it says that,

> $X$ = the  distance  of  the point  where  the  dart  lands  from  the  origin  of  the  plate.

Then it says that

> $(X <  a)$ denotes that  the point is inside the circle of  radius $a$.

and then it goes on with a calculation of areas of circles.

See the calculation. It is using the formula of the area of a circle.

Why does the area of a circle come into play?

why can't we use distance to find the answer?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where did a distance become an area? $X$ takes values in $[0,1)$.

Comment: The question in the title doesn't seem to be the same as the question in the question body. "Why does $X<a$ mean the point is in the circle" and "Why does the area come into play" are two different questions. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @copper.hat, kindly see the edit.

Comment: @JackM, edited.

Comment: You can use the distance to solve the problem but it is a little more complicated.

Comment: @copper.hat, yeah that is what I want to see.

Comment: Give me a minute.

Comment: @copper.hat, take 15 minutes.

Comment: I’m sorry, I am foreign to probability theory, but (I think) I know that to speak of probabilities, you need a probability space and a probability measure on it. Here the probability space seems to be the disc-shaped area $D$ of the plate, of area measure $\pi$, and the measure $P(S)$ of a subset $S\subset D$ will be $\text{area}(S)/\pi$. This would measure the probability of hitting within $S$. Once you grant and understand this, the answer should become clear to you.

Comment: The last formula in my answer is what I was getting at by 'complicated' in my comments above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dart must land in the circle $B(0,1)$ and it is equally likely to land anywhere.

So, the probability that the dart lies in $B(0,1)$ is one.

Since the probability is uniform, if you pick a shape that lies in the disk of area $A$
then the probability of the dart landing there is 
${A \over \text{total area}} = {A \over \pi}$.

Now take an annulus described by $0 \le r  \le r+d < 1$. The area is given by
$\pi (d^2-r^2)$, that is,
$P[r \le X \le r+d] = d^2-r^2$.

From the formula you can compute the probability density, then
$f_X(r)=\lim_{d \to 0}{P[X \le r+d]-P[X \le r]\over d} = 2r$.

Then, for example,
$P[a<X<b] = \int_a^b f_X(r)dr = \int_a^b (2r)dr = b^2-a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that every point is equally likely to be hit. The long answer is that by "likely" I'm referring not to probability (which for one point is unhelpfully $0$) but probability density, so another way to say it is the probability per area, of a region being it, is constant. Therefore, probabilities are all expressible as area ratios.

I imagine you were thinking, "why can't I go by radius ratios"? Roughly speaking, because the further you are from the centre the "more" is that far away (not in the sense of more points - it's always infinitely many - or more area - the area is $0$ - but in the sense of the circumference at that distance). Therefore, the radial way isn't fair.

Incidentally, more complicated probability-on-circle problems [require careful definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

Comment: This is 'almost' a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking (in (i)) the probability that the dart lands closer than $x$ to the center, but it doesn't care in which direction. Therefore your probability is the ratio of the area of radius $x$ to the area of the entire plate. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: why can't we use distance to find the anwser?

Answer (score 0):

We throw a dart at a plate of area $A$. Now we take some small region of the plate (say the bullseye), of area $B$. Then the probability of the dart landing in that region is $B/A$. That's the formula being used in the question.

The "area of target region over area of entire region" formula is a standard formula used in most of these situations. It corresponds to a situation where the dart is equally likely to land anywhere.

Comment: why can't we use distance to find the answer?

Comment: @user366312 What does that mean? Use distance how?

Comment: you tell me as they are telling us that `X = the distance of the point where the dart lands from the origin of the plate.`

Comment: For now, forget the question. Do you understand my answer? Does the $B/A$ formula seem reasonable to you, for the probability of landing in a region of area $B$?

Comment: Yes I understand the whole thing. But, my question is elsewhere. Kindly, read the original question again.

Comment: @user366312 Okay. Then if you understand it, use this formula to work out the probability of a dart landing inside of a circle of radius $a$ (on a larger board of radius $l$). What answer do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is what we called in school *probability problems with geometry*. Think the usual formula for naive probability calculation
$$
\frac{\text{number of a specific outcome}}{\text{number of all outcomes}}.
$$
In this case it would be really hard to determine the *number of all outcomes* since there are infinitely many points on the dart board where your dart may land. At this point we decide to use the area of a circe as a sort of "number of points in a certain area" or "number of outcomes in a certain part of the dartboard".

One can use this method when the events we are looking at are not discrete but continuous.

Comment: Much better answer than the others!

Comment: @user366312 So, you understand now?

Comment: "One can use this method when the events we are looking at are not discrete but continuous." --- so, does all continuous problems involve geometry?

Comment: All geometric problems should involve geometry.

Comment: You can think like that, yes. Or rather that we try to use geometry because it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @user366312 You want to discuss this in chat instead of making a mile long comment-chain here?